# Из-за чего list index out of range?

Tags: python, список, openpyxl, python-docx

Можете подсказать в чем заключается ошибка? Может я слепой? Схожая проблема возникает уже не в первый раз
Использую python-docx 0.8.10 и openpyxl 3.0.7

```
Exception in Tkinter callback<br/>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "D:\program files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__<br/>
    return self.func(*args)<br/>
  File "D:\rab\Anton2\main.py", line 96, in check_zap<br/>
    self.list_massiv()<br/>
  File "D:\rab\Anton2\main.py", line 174, in list_massiv<br/>
    self.zapis_dannih()<br/>
  File "D:\rab\Anton2\main.py", line 186, in zapis_dannih<br/>
    stand = str(self.listZapStand[i])<br/>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
###Первая часть###
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'AObject\Прайс услуг.xlsx') #Начинается с B2
        wbsheet = wb['Лист1']
        dis = wbsheet.max_row
        for i in range(1, dis-1):
            if wbsheet[dis][2].value == self.TypeSh.get():
                if wbsheet[dis][3].value == self.DliVBu:
                    if wbsheet[dis][4].value == self.Slozhnost:
                        wbsheet[dis][5].value = self.Srok.get()
                        for s in range(0, 13):
                            self.listZapStand[s] = wbsheet[1][s+1].value #Названия столбцов
                            self.listZap[s] = wbsheet[dis][s+1].value #Сами данные
self.pif += 1 #Изначально = 0

###Вторая часть###
        for s in range(0, self.pif):
            for i in range(1, 13):
                stand = str(self.listZapStand[i]) #Ошибка возникает здесь
                izmen = str(self.LZ[s][i]) #И здесь
                document.add_paragraph(stand + izmen).Times_New_Roman = True
```

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки

Answer (score 3):

На ваш вопрос "Из-за чего list index out of range?" отвечаю: ваша ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу списка (или другому итерируемому объекту) по индексу, а такого элемента в вашем списке нет.  А вот где она возникает - ясно и четко написано в сообщении об ошибке, которое вы нам показать не захотели.

Заниматься угадыванием, в каком именно месте вашего скрипта произошла ошибка - особого желания нет, но теперь вы получили информацию о причине. Поэтому найти  ошибку ее самостоятельно исправить - для вас труда составить не должно.

На будущее - делайте вывод, как надо (и как не надо) задавать вопросы.